# Airplay XPC Helper consuming 2.5 GB of memory?

Tags: memory, airplay

Activity monitor showing Airplay XPC Helper process using 2.5GB of memory which seems like an obnoxious amount of memory for a Mac OS native audio network process. I do use Airplay regularly when home to stream Apple Music audio to Airplay speakers on the network. However currently, at the time of screenshot, I'm remote and NOT doing that, still this process is consuming this much memory.

Is there any reason / explanation for this or is this a true memory leak issue?

[image]

Comment: Memory is never an issue until you run out of it. macOS handles this pretty well on its own. The picture is cropped so we can't see the overall usage at the bottom, which would help.

Answer (score 1):

2.5 GB seems a lot, it's 6.4 MB here. If memory is tight, you can kill the process from within Activity Monitor or with `sudo kill -9 PID`, it will restart automatically.